# Passing in query parameters from the app to the URL?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-navigation

I have migrated from Navigator 1 to Navigator 2.0 for URL support in Flutter Web. When I navigate between pages, the URL changes successfully ( / -> /search), and when I input parameters into the URL (/search?query=chocolate), the query is returned with values to the correct page but when I navigate between pages within the app, it will only change the path and not add the query parameters to the browser's search bar. This means that when I refresh the page the state is lost.

Has anyone managed to achieve passing query parameters to the page URL? And if so, how?

Comment: Please note the issue I encountered was a framework issue and has now been patched in the master and beta branches.